# How to get a @ as a column name and $ as value in Snowflake Sql

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I received json unstructured data that I attempted to parse but was unable to do so using json_parse.
I have an entire column for this kind of data, from which I'm providing a sample of the data and the results I need. Could you please advise me on a strategy?
**Sample Data**:-

```
  [
  {
    "$": "5.1.0.18",
    "@": "agon"
  },
  {
    "$": "199891e7-d75c",
    "@": "aged"
  },
  {
    "$": "SVE",
    "@": "sta"
  },
  {
    "$": "230Z",
    "@": "lasIn"
  },
  {
    "$": "69.11",
    "@": "conom"
  },
  {
    "$": "Invplete",
    "]@": "chus"
  },
  {
    "$": "Win",
    "@": "pla"
  },
  {
    "$": "A_PM,AGENT_SCA,ANT_VM",
    "@": "adMe"
  },
  {
    "$": [
      {
        "$": "VULIGS-M-2.5.77-3",
        "@": "vm"
      },
      {
        "$": "VULNS-SA-2.5.767-2",
        "@": "sca"
      }
    ],
    "@": "manstVeon",
    "sa": 1,
    "vrm": 0
  },
  {
    "$": [
      {
        "$": 3905,
        "@": "id"
      },
      {
        "$": "Sta Cnt - No Auo Uate",
        "@": "name"
      }
    ],
    "@": "agtion",
    "id": 0,
    "name": 1
  },
  {
    "$": [
      {
        "$": "abe7-0aa7141fe2e2",
        "@": "actId"
      },
      {
        "$": "IT t",
        "@": "title"
      }
    ],
    "@": "acey",
    "acId": 0,
    "title": 1
  }
]
```

made changes  in the code section
**Required Output**
[image: Required Output]

Comment: That’s not valid json - you can put it through any online json validator and check it

Comment: I just made change in json

Comment: Your JSON and the Required Output don't seem to be aligned. For example, the text values "aeddule" or "AT_M" in your required output aren't in your JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax to extract JSON attributes that have special characters in their names:

```
GET(JSON, '@')::string,
GET(JSON, '$')::string
```

For your query it looks like you're also needing to deal with flattening and pivoting, which gives you something like this (reduced to a smaller set as an example, since I'm not 100% sure how you're expecting to get to your requested output)

```
with json_cte as (
select parse_json('[
  {
    "$": "5.1.0.18",
    "@": "agon"
  },
  {
    "$": "199891e7-d75c",
    "@": "aged"
  }]'
  ) as json_array
)
, attributes (
  select
      GET(a.value, '@')::string attr,
      GET(a.value, '$')::string val
  from json_cte,
  lateral flatten(input => json_array) a
)

select *
from attributes  
pivot(max(val) for attr in ('agon', 'aged'));
```